Why Does the Unit Cell Change During My SIESTA Calculation
I am performing calculations using SIESTA, and I noticed that the unit cell dimensions are changing during the simulation. Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how to control it?
Here are some details about my setup
SystemLabel      1BN-1

NumberOfAtoms    8

NumberOfSpecies  3
%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1    6  C.gga
    2    5  B.gga
    3    7  N.gga
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel
%block LatticeVectors
        5.0205340385         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
       -2.5102670193         4.3479100179         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        15.0000000000
%endblock LatticeVectors
AtomicCoordinatesFormat NotScaledCartesianAng
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
     0.000000000     1.449303000     7.500000000    1
    -1.255134000     3.623258000     7.500000000    1
     2.510267000     1.449303000     7.500000000    2
     1.255134000     3.623258000     7.500000000    1
     1.255134000     0.724652000     7.500000000    1
     0.000000000     2.898607000     7.500000000    3
     3.765401000     0.724652000     7.500000000    1
     2.510267000     2.898607000     7.500000000    3
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

# K-points
#kgrid_cutoff        0  Ang

#%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
#1   0   0   0.0
#0   1   0   0.0
#0   0   1   0.0
#%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack

 
#%block GeometryConstraints
#position from  1 to  180
#%endblock GeometryConstraints

PAO.BasisSize     DZP
PAO.EnergyShift   0.03 eV
MD.TypeOfRun      CG
MD.VariableCell    false
MaxSCFIterations  400
MD.NumCGsteps     0
MD.MaxForceTol    0.005  eV/Ang
MeshCutoff        150 Ry
DM.MixingWeight   0.02
DM.NumberPulay   3
WriteCoorXmol   .true.
WriteMullikenPop    1
XC.functional       GGA
XC.authors          PBE
SolutionMethod  diagon
ElectronicTemperature  25.86 meV
SaveRho        .true.


#UseSaveData     true
#DM.UseSaveDM    true
#MD.UseSaveXV    true
#MD.UseSaveCG    true




 

The cell after siesta calclution :
         13.370161376       0.000000000       0.000000000
          0.000000000      11.036039476       0.000000000
          0.000000000       0.000000000       9.184564484
           8
  1     6       0.000000000       0.131324557       0.816587440
  1     6      -0.093875755       0.328311439       0.816587440
  2     5       0.187751436       0.131324557       0.816587440
  1     6       0.093875755       0.328311439       0.816587440
  1     6       0.093875755       0.065662324       0.816587440
  3     7       0.000000000       0.262649205       0.816587440
  1     6       0.281627192       0.065662324       0.816587440
  3     7       0.187751436       0.262649205       0.816587440


Observation: The cell change completly

+1. Welcome to our community!

Normally, I always put the logical values in between dots. I don't know if using "MD.VariableCell    .false." instead "MD.VariableCell    false" will fix it. Also, as I rarely do cell optimizations, even add "MD.VariableCell    false" to my input.
